# Is it possible to calculate AWT and ATA for SJF( shortest job first ) based on priority?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, scheduling

so far I know that in SJF the execution is done first which BT is low based on the AT.

but if there also attach Priority, how do reach the solution

```
Process    Arrival Time        Burst Time        Priority

P1             7                   3              2

P2             5                   2              4

P3             4                   5              1

P4             0                   4             3
```

Comment: It depends what your scheduler does with the priority.  If SJF is only a tie-break for equal priority jobs, then in your case the job priority is the only thing that determines what to start next.  But if it's just a weighting factor or adjustment to the job cost, then you need to know what scheduling heuristic is actually used.  (For example, Unix `nice` levels don't totally starve "nicer" jobs even if a nice=-19 task has an infinite loop.  But that's a process scheduler for context switching, not a batch job scheduler where you don't interleave work.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the valuable feedback. Now I am clear about that. This was about how manually solve rather than code. we can consider or be concerned about priority when two or more tasks AT and BT same we give priority to which one has the highest priority otherwise follow SJF.

Comment: IMO It depends on the requirement of the question. Sometimes can do SJF only or priority only. If must combine, then choose the highest priority with shortest jobs. If more than 1 job fit the criteria, choose the shortest jobs between them.